# created a pop up modal with no error but it isnt showing the image/description

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]Created a catalog, when you click on the "more info" button a pop up modal. pops up but the image and description isnt showing in the pop up modal

```
let { itemInfo } = this.props;
let removeCom;

if (itemInfo.description) {
removeCom = itemInfo.description
.replace("?", "")
.replace('<td width="110" height="">', "")
.replace("http://extranet.acetools.com/Catalog/", 
 "assets/img/items/")
.replace((/<INPUT[^>]*>/gmi), "")
.split('<CENTER><FONT COLOR="RED">', 1);

console.log(removeCom);
}

return (
<h6 className="card-header" style={cardHeader}>
Item # {this.props.itemInfo.item_no} - {this.props.itemInfo.item}
</h6>
<div className="card-body" style={cardBody}>
<div className="row">    
  <div className="col-6" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: 
  removeCom}} style={text}>
  </div>
  <div className="col-6">
    <img src={this.props.itemInfo.image} alt="" style= . 
 {productImg}></img>
  </div>
  {/* <div>hello</div> */}
</div>
 <div className="row">

 <button className="btn btn-outline-primary" onClick= . 
 {this.props.onClose} style={closeButton}>
  Close
 </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Franky, check this example out:

```
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native'

class ErrorModal extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { modal: { closeModal, params } } = this.props
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>An error occured!</Text>
        <Text>{params.errorMessage}</Text>
        <Button onPress={closeModal} title="OK" />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default ErrorModal
```

Check to see if you're passing props through use of destructuring and check your routes.  I hope this helps.